# Solving $\sin \left( x+\frac{\pi }{3} \right) -\sin \left( x-\frac{\pi }{3} \right) = \sin\left(x\right)$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm struggling with solving the following trigonometric equation:

$$
\sin \left(x+\frac{\pi}{3}\right)-\sin \left(x-\frac{\pi}{3}\right)=\sin x,
$$

and I need some help. I tried to use the sum and difference of sines formula, which states that $\sin(a \pm b) = \sin a \cos b \pm \cos a \sin b$, to simplify the left-hand side of the equation:

\begin{align}
\sin \left(x+\frac{\pi}{3}\right)-\sin \left(x-\frac{\pi}{3}\right) &= \left(\sin x \cos \frac{\pi}{3} + \cos x \sin \frac{\pi}{3}\right) - \left(\sin x \cos \frac{\pi}{3} - \cos x \sin \frac{\pi}{3}\right)\\
&= 2\cos x \sin \frac{\pi}{3}\\
&= \sqrt{3} \cos x,
\end{align}

but I'm not sure if this is correct. If it is, then I can rewrite the equation as:

$$
\sqrt{3} \cos x = \sin x,
$$

which leads to:

$$
x = \arctan \sqrt{3} = \frac{\pi}{3},
$$

or

$$
x = \pi - \arctan \sqrt{3} = \frac{2\pi}{3}.
$$

However, I'm not sure how to proceed from here to find the sum of the solutions that lie in the interval $[-\frac{4\pi}{3}, 2\pi]$. Can anyone please help me with this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5):

You correctly reduced the problem to
$$\sqrt{3}\cos x = \sin x$$
then implicitly obtained
$$\tan x = \sqrt{3}$$
A particular solution of the equation is
$$x = \arctan(\sqrt{3}) = \frac{\pi}{3}$$
Since tangent is periodic with period $\pi$, the general solution is
$$x = \frac{\pi}{3} + k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$$
Since we want solutions in the interval $[-\frac{4\pi}{3}, 2\pi]$, we wish to find $k$ such that
$$-\frac{4\pi}{3} \leq \frac{\pi}{3} + k\pi \leq 2\pi$$
which is equivalent to
$$-\frac{5\pi}{3} \leq k\pi \leq \frac{5\pi}{3}$$
The only such values are $k = -1, 0, 1$.  Hence, the possible solutions are
$$x = -\frac{2\pi}{3}, \frac{\pi}{3}, \frac{4\pi}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

Reckon with the periodicity of trigonometric functions.

You correctly derive $\sin(x)=\sqrt3\cos(x)$. This may be reduced to $\tan (x)=\sqrt3$ which, as you also see correctly, has a solution $x=\pi/3$ -- but not $2\pi/3$, where if you check you find the sines and cosines have the wrong pair of signs. (You have $\sin(\pi-x)=\sin(x)$ but not $\cos(\pi-x)=\cos(x)$.)

Now **the tangent function has a period of $\pi$.** So if $\pi/3$ has the correct tangent value, so must

$\pi/3+k\pi=(k+3)\pi/3, k\in\mathbb{Z}.$

You are to find the values of the integer $k$ that give solutions in the required interval $[-4\pi/3,2\pi]$ and add up the resulting values for $x$.